# sharing ios code in XCode via linking to external directories of code

Tags: xcode, ios

I'm trying to do this.. I drag in my shared code folder, I 'link' it, I don't copy it. It shows up as a blue folder in XCode, but I keep getting a whole bunch of "No such file or directory" errors in XCode against all my linked code. If I tick the 'copy' option when importing the shared code into XCode it works. But I don't want to have multiple copies of shared code laying around... HELP!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tick "Create Groups for any added folders". Don't know why it doesn't work otherwise.